# distinct contiguous blocks in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
 x1=[np.nan, 'a','a','a', np.nan,np.nan,'b','b','c',np.nan,'b','b', np.nan]
 ty1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':x1})
```

Do you know how I can get a list of tuples containing the start and end indices of distinct contiguous blocks? For example for the dataframe above,

```
[(1,3), (6,7), (8,8), (10,11)].
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `shift` and `cumsum` to create 'id's for each contiguous block:

```
In [5]: blocks = (ty1 != ty1.shift()).cumsum()

In [6]: blocks
Out[6]:
    name
0      1
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      3
5      4
6      5
7      5
8      6
9      7
10     8
11     8
12     9
```

You are only interested in those blocks that are not NaN, so filter for that:

```
In [7]: blocks = blocks[ty1['name'].notnull()]

In [8]: blocks
Out[8]:
    name
1      2
2      2
3      2
6      5
7      5
8      6
10     8
11     8
```

And then, we can get the first and last index for each 'id':

```
In [10]: blocks.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: (x.index[0], x.index[-1]))
Out[10]:
name
2      (1, 3)
5      (6, 7)
6      (8, 8)
8    (10, 11)
dtype: object
```

Although, if this last step is necessary will depend on what you want to do with it (working with tuples as elements in dataframes in not really recommended). Maybe having the 'id's can already be enough.

Comment: this is excellent joris! thank you so much. Yes, the last step maybe I end up having one array for the starting position indices and one array for the end position indices. My choice of "tuples list" was sort of arbitrary.

Comment: Hey Joris, old question but I was linked to this question and was wondering if I could this logic to my own issue here , would you be able to help if you happen to have the time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411287/summing-a-time-series-column-upon-it-self-with-a-condition?noredirect=1#comment95633975_54411287

Comment: Alternatively: `blocks = ty1.diff().ne(0).cumsum()`